# Coinbase API - Conversion Endpoint /conversions

Tags: coinbase-api

After plenty of late nights and head scratching I have navigated the murky world of the 'Coinbase Pro API' and integrated it with a new trading app I have made.  I have hit a snag however and am baffled as to why.  Had a snoop around all the usual 'Google' hotspots and I can find similar questions but no answers.  I hope someone can help?!

Simply put I want to do a conversion, see the seemingly simple endpoint to do so:

- https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_postconversion
- https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/conversions

Now; it's not an authentication issue etc.  As mentioned, I have the API fully working in my app, accounts, orders, ticker etc, all no problem.  Just conversions I have an issue with.  I am posting the relevant variables as suggested:

Example:

```json
{"to":"ETH","amount":"50.00","from":"BTC","profile_id":"my_profile_id"}
```

No matter what currencies I try, the response is always the same:

```json
{"message":"Cannot convert BTC to ETH"}
```

With different coin ID's of course.

Full on drawing a blank here!  Kind of a useless output from Coinbase?

I'd love to know if anyone has cracked this?

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You can’t do a conversion unless their values are linked, such as USDC-USD. What you are looking to do is a market buy of some type, I would suggest a limit order as you can specify price options."

https://forums.coinbasecloud.dev/t/unable-to-successfully-convert-crypto-to-another-crypto/289

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Understood and thank you.  After some back and forth with Coinbase support I found while conversion is possible in app, fee free, in API it’s an order with the relevant fees.  A little frustrating but hopefully they will allow API conversion fee free soon

Answer (score -1):

"You can’t do a conversion unless their values are linked, such as USDC-USD. How to determine if a conversion is linked, I'm not following this answer.

Is this what you mean?

{"to":"ETH-USD","amount":"50.00","from":"BTC-USD","profile_id":"my_profile_id"}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).